# Loading CSV File as Vector Layer from URL,Remote,Server (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, vector, csv

QGIS 3.24

I want to load a CSV file as a Vector Layer from my Server. The CSV file is regularly updated with new coordinates from a GPS tracker.

My code:

```
uri = "/vsicurl/http://mydomain.at/iot/gps/cow1.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4326&xField={}&yField={}".format(";", "longitude", "latitude")
csv_file = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'cow1', 'delimitedtext')

#Check if layer is valid
if not csv_file.isValid():
    print ("Layer not loaded")
 

#QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(csv_file)
```

If I use a local path with "file:///" it works.

```
uri = "file:///home/data/iot/gps/cow1.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4326&xField={}&yField={}".format(";", "longitude", "latitude")
```

But how it works with an URL?

I wrote the script with the buid-in editor. It is executed within the python console.

I get no error, when running. A new layer shows up in the layer menu with the attention symbol and mouseover text "Layer data source could not be found"

---

> what happens if you take off the vsicurl ?

```
uri = "http://my-domain.at/iot/gps/cow1.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:4326&xField={}&yField={}".format(";", "longitude", "latitude")
```

Nothing changes. The same problem: "Layer data source could not be found"

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/431237/edit) to specify how you are running that code and what happens when you do, including any error messages as text, not screenshots.

Comment: what happens if you take off the `vsicurl` ?

Comment: Nothing changes. The same problem: "Layer data source could not be found"